# Way to find rows with duplicates in one column which contains all the values of a list in another column

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way in `pandas` library to find all the rows with duplicates in one column that contains all the values from a list in another column? For example, in my df I have an `ID` column and a `Value` column. The `ID` column has duplicating IDs but a different str value in the `Value` column.

i.e

```
('1,A', '1,B', '1,C', '2,A', '2,B', '3,A', '3,B', '3,C', '4,A', '4,B', '5,B', '5,C') 
Legend: 'ID,Value'
```

I want to return the IDs that have only have 'A', 'B' in their 'Value' column. So in this example, the rows for IDs '2' and '4'. I tried using the `.isin(list)` with `list = ['A', 'B']` but with `.isin()` it returns every instance where an item from the list occurs. Is there a way I can return the rows where the IDs only have 'A' and 'B'?

I am getting this: `('1,A', '1,B', '2,A', '2,B', '3,A', '3,B', '4,A', '4,B', '5,B')`

I want to get this: `('2,A', '2,B', '4,A', '4,B')`

Comment: Please show us the actual code you've tried so far.

Comment: You should structure you list as a dictionary instead. Ex: `l = { "1" : ["A", "B", "C"], "2" : ["A", "B"] }`. Then you just iteration through each dictionary key to see if they contain only A and B.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth Here is the code I tried. 

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '5', '5'],
                   'Values':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']})
print(df)

list = ['A', 'B']
new_df = df[df['Values'].isin(list)]
print(new_df)

desired_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['2', '2', '4', '4'],
                   'Values':['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']})
print(desired_df)

Answer (score 0):

Here this works technically:

```
better = {}
for i in range(len(df["ID"])):
    id = df["ID"][i]
    if not better.__contains__(id):
        better[id] = []
    better[id].append(df["Values"][i])
print(better)
s = {"ID":[], "Values":[]}
for i in better:
    if "C" not in better[i]:
        s["ID"].append(i)
        s["ID"].append(i)
        s["Values"].append("A")
        s["Values"].append("B")
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group that same bool mask by `ID`, which will return a bool series, e.g.:

```
bool_ser = df['Value'].isin(["A", "B"]).groupby(df['ID']).all()

# outputs something like this in your case:
'''
ID
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: Value, dtype: bool
'''
```

And then you `loc` the original dataframe using only the `ID`s with true value in the series:

```
df.loc[df["ID"].isin(s[s].index)]

# outputs a df similar to this:
'''
  ID Value
3  2     A
4  2     B
8  4     A
9  4     B
'''
# ignore the index labels, they come from a simple testing df
```

I'm like 200% sure there are better methods if you delve a little more into pd docs, but this should work.